# Delete a part of line in a file where elements are defined by patterns

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk, sed

I have a csv file containing lines where each line is composed as it follows:

```
Id="1" date="dd:mm:yyyy:hh:ss" body"abcdefghijklmo..." Owner="123" editor="456"
```

I would like to cut the part related to body and preserve the rest of the elements of the file. The problem is the "body" part changes its NF, and when i try with sed -e '/Body/,/Owner/d' it does not work either.

Any one can help.

Bests

Comment: Better read [ask], [edit] your question and show your attempts together with desired output.

Comment: There isn't a single comma in that sample input - in what way is that a Comma-Separated-Value file? What does `the "body" part changes its NF` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use perl with a non-greedy match

```
while(<>) {
   s! body\".*?\"!!;
   print;
}
```

which will remove the text between `body"` and the next quotation mark.  Normally `*` will match as many characters as possible, but the `?` tells it to finish that match at the first quote.

Comment: thank you i'll will try, but i never used perl before.